# Get list of values in div element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding items dynamically with ajax_select (app with builtin js script to add items), it is adding items as

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="control-label" for="id_colours">Colours</label>
    <input type="text" name="colours_text" id="id_colours_text" value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input">
    <input type="hidden" name="colours" id="id_colours" value="|1|7|2|" data-ajax-select="autocompleteselectmultiple" data-plugin-options="{&quot;html&quot;: true, &quot;source&quot;:
&quot;/ajax_select/ajax_lookup/colours&quot;}" data-changed="true">

     <div id="id_colours_on_deck" class="results_on_deck">
        <div id="id_colours_on_deck_1">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_1id_colours">X</span> White
        </div>

        <div id="id_colours_on_deck_7">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_7id_colours">X</span> Yellow
        </div>

        <div id="id_colours_on_deck_2">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_2id_colours">X</span> Black
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I added `White, Yellow and Black` these are inside div of id = `id_colours_on_deck`, how can I get the list of all colours in `id_colours_on_deck`.
I am not friendly with jquery probably here I can get the answer.

Comment: You are mention only `White` Color in  `kill_1id_colours`

Comment: ohh, its my mistake sorry, I have edited the question

Comment: @PankajSharma FYI, I updated my answer with a much better, and more performant solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate over the `div`s using `each()` and grab only the text using `.contents()[1]`, like this:

```
("div[id^='id_colours_on_deck_']").each(function(){
    $($(this).contents()[1]).text();
})
```

Answer (score 3):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to "extract" the colors you have mentioned inside the divs? (So White, Yellow, Black)

Using jQuery, you should be able to do something like this with jQuery: (however, this will also include the "X" that is inside the span, so that will need to be looked at)

```
$("#id_colours_on_deck").find("div[id^=id_colours_on_deck]").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it's dynamically added you need to use $(document) or $('body') to find your elements as jQuery works with the DOM that's loaded on document load. Which is why newly added elements can't be targeted using conventional ways:

```
$(document).find('#my-dynamic-element'); //this is how you get the dynamically added element
```

then to get your data you'd use something like:

```
$(document).find('#id_colours_on_deck_7').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use plain javascript, [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild).

With `querySelectorAll` you get the selection of `div` with a color text, and with `lastChild` you avoid getting the `span` and can grab the *text node* holding the color.

Stack snippet

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#id_colours_on_deck div')).forEach(el => {
  console.log( el.lastChild.textContent );
})
```

```html
<div id="id_colours_on_deck" class="results_on_deck">
  <div id="id_colours_on_deck_1">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_1id_colours">X</span> White
  </div>

  <div id="id_colours_on_deck_7">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_7id_colours">X</span> Yellow
  </div>

  <div id="id_colours_on_deck_2">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_2id_colours">X</span> Black
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment how to be compatible with older browsers.

Here is an option that will do that, far way back in time :)

```js
var list = document.getElementById('id_colours_on_deck').children;
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var el = list[i].lastChild;
  console.log( (el.textContent || el.innerText) );
}
```

```html
<div id="id_colours_on_deck" class="results_on_deck">
  <div id="id_colours_on_deck_1">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_1id_colours">X</span> White
  </div>

  <div id="id_colours_on_deck_7">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_7id_colours">X</span> Yellow
  </div>

  <div id="id_colours_on_deck_2">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_2id_colours">X</span> Black
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is really a very good solution, I already up voted your answer and if you think question is good you can also vote up, tell me is this compatible with old browsers , Internet Explorer and phone browser ?

Comment: @PankajSharma `lastChild` is an old tech, `querySelectorAll` from IE8 ... so yes, it works with older browsers and phone's

Comment: @PankajSharma Oh, and a `for...loop` instead of the `Array.from` as the latter is newer .... so for real old one's (IE6), I added a 2nd sample.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an each function, something like this.

```
$('#id_colours_on_deck div').each(function) {
    $('#id_colours_on_deck div').html();
```

}

This however will include the X from the span tag.

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/shawnw/4yaem85k/12/

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to use this technique

```
$("div[id^=id_colours_on_deck_]").clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a very small change to your HTML by adding the color name to a `span` with class `.color-name`, and have generated the following answer:

```js
var colorParentList = $("#id_colours_on_deck span.color-name");
colorParentList.each(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id_colours_on_deck" class="results_on_deck">
  <div id="id_colours_on_deck_1">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_1id_colours">X</span> <span class="color-name">White</span>
  </div>

  <div id="id_colours_on_deck_7">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_7id_colours">X</span> <span class="color-name">Yellow</span>
  </div>

  <div id="id_colours_on_deck_2">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="kill_2id_colours">X</span><span class="color-name"> Black</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this was helpful.